# Use Copies of Forms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

i have a form that pulls in data, crunches numbers, does things. it works perfectly.

the problem is the code is i can only access one market at a time and i want to have the ability to access more than one.

i could duplicate the current form x 4 let's say, so then after i login i could have access to 4 markets, instead of 1. but the code is a little dense, and i would be stuck with however many forms i have hardwired, instead of having the flexibility to replicate the initial form, and then access another market.

the simplest and fastest way to accomplish this would be to use some code that would 'pop-up' a clone of the existing form, if such a thing is possible.

Comment: I bet the code that deals with say, Market1, is all in the form and control events?  and coded for whatever Market1 is?  Are these Markets otherwise the same in constituency?

Comment: page???? is this asp?

Comment: no, vb.net, vb 2010 - the project has one form with (upon right click on the form) one long 'page' behind it with several subs, classes, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you are after, you want something like this (first part is VERY similar to "Michael's" answer):

In the form:

```
Public MarketCOde As String        ' whatever it is.

Public Sub New(mktCode As String)
   ' leave this line alone
   InitializeComponent

   MarketCOde = mktCode
End sub
```

Now anywhere the code in your form needs to know which market it is working on, it can reference `MarketCode`.

To create a form to work with a new market:

```
 Dim frmAsia As New FORMNAME("ASIA")
```

Since the form will REQUIRE a market code, we are passing it when we create the form. We arent cloning the form, but creating an `instance` of it to work with different, but specific, markets. Now, keep reading because here is the bad news:

If all the code is embedded in the form, it will have to be refactored to reference MarketCode instead of the hardcoded references likely there now.  Next, your app needs a new way to start since the mainform wont get that critical MktCode arg from VB.

The best thing is to add a market picker form, and make that the start up form in Project Properties.  Add buttons to create each new market form you need:

```
' this is a new button on a new form to make Market Form instances.
Sub button1_click......

  ' USE THE ACTUAL FormName from your code!
  Dim frmCentral as New FORMNAME("CENTRAL")   
  frmCentral.Show

 End Sub

' each button makes a new market form,
Sub button2_click......                     ' NOTE: Btn 2!

  ' the FormName from your code
  Dim frmAsia as New FORMNAME("ASIA")   
  frmAsia.Show

 End Sub
```

One button, **one form instance name**, one market

This is also the startup form to launch the first one.  Be sure to set it as the startup form In Project Properties.

Comment: thanks for the reply ... ok, i created 2 new forms. one form i have 2 buttons on. click one i get the form i want. that works. but when i click it again, no new additional form pops. thinking it may be because of the form content, i created a blank form. no code issues there. the next button on the start-up form makes the 2nd form pop, but any subsequent clicks of the button do nothing. as far as the other code you mention, i dont see where to put it on the original form, and dont get what it has to do with re-launching the main form.

Comment: Edited the answer.  A) a second click WONT create a new form, there is ONE instance of frmAsia EVER.  A second click RECREATES it. B) "the other code" is probably your SUb New.  Look in the form procedure dropdn list, you will see a New at the top.  The line before it ...`Public MarketCode` goes near the top of the form. Classes etc in the "long page behind" the form will need that as part of the refactoring. C) we are NOT re-launching the main form, but making NEW INSTANCES of it for specific markets.

Comment: ok, i will keep working on it... but so you know how the market data is obtained ... when the main form is launched a required login form pops before the vb form appears. to choose a market there is a dropdown combo that auto-populates when the vb form loads (if the login is successful) ... so basically when the vb form launches no market is selected ... i want to have x# of these 'blank' forms to then select from the drop down, then submit and get the data ... hard to explain w/o a visual ... but i will see what i can do ... thanks again for the reply

Comment: In THAT case, you dont need the new frm with 4 buttons, but you do need to modify how it is launched from the login form.  PRIOR to doing the existing form setup stuff, **it** needs to be the one to create frm instances (`dim frmXXX as New FormMain(MktCode)`).  Then, rather than refactoring code, all you really need is a way to show that LogIn form again so that you can launch a new Mkt Form.  Since the current form already works with the 4 mkts, all you need is multiple instances of it which is what `dim frmXXX as New FormMain(MktCode)` does.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to you to create Properties on the MarketForm that you can set externally, so that each instance relates to a specific Market. I've used MarketName but you'll have to figure out what makes sense in your case.

Inside the code for MarketForm create something like this (you'll need to modify your existing code to use it instead of however you are currently picking a market)

```
Public Property MarketName As String
```

With object-oriented programming it is easy to create different instances of any object (Form in this case).

```
Dim myMarketForm1 As New MarketForm
myMarketForm1.MarketName = "Eastern"
myMarketForm1.Show()

Dim myMarketForm2 As New MarketForm
myMarketForm2.MarketName = "Central"
myMarketForm2.Show()
`... and so on
```

Comment: If the marketform requires the market identity to run (which sounds like it is the case), then `MarketName` should be passed as an arg in the constructor so it cant be forgotten/missed.

Comment: `Sub New` does not run in the designer - add a Break, Beep, msgbox or console.writeline to see.  If it did run, 'InitializeComponent' would execute and all the controls (and form) would be respond to clicks instead of drilling to event code.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936142/adding-an-overloaded-constructor-to-a-winform

Comment: Seems you are correct about that. I must have been thinking of when using Forms Inheritance, if you only have a constructor with args the inherited Form cannot be displayed in the designer (saying it can't find a constructor). Not sure why it is different in that case but it is something to be aware of...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you might be looking for is this...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim frm As New Form1
    frm.Show()
End Sub
```

In this example, when `Button1` is clicked, it creates a copy of `Form1` and displays it. The button can be clicked multiple times to produce multiple copies of `Form1`. The button can even be placed on `Form1` itself.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply ... i get this error: "frm cannot refer to itself through its default instance use Me instead" i then change it to Me.from.Show() and nothing happens, debug mode or compiled.

Comment: @user2835653, Is the name of your form `frm` ? If so, use a different variable name. If not, it might make it more clear if you could post the code.