# Passing parameters between two forms in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, forms, datagridview

I currently have about 5 forms in my application. I'm building a 6th form - frmSummary however, I'd like to be able to access it from all forms. in frmSummary I am planning to add a DataGridView, where I'll be displaying data related to that form. I'm thinking that I should either create a global variable such as

```
dim FrmName as String
```

In each form I would have a cmdSummary button so that On click_event, I would do something like

```
frmName ="CustomerInfo"
```

Currently the way my application is set up is that I hve a mdiForm and within it, each form is a child so on opening new forms I do something like...

```
Private Sub cmdSummary_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSummary.Click
    Dim NewMDIChild As New frmClientEligibilityReferral()

    frmName = "CustomerInfo" --since this will be comeing from frmCustomerInfo
    NewMDIChild.MdiParent = MDIform1
    NewMDIChild.Show()
    MDIForm1.Show()

End Sub
```

So I do something like that on opening my new form. My question is how can I pass the parameter to my form frmSummary....here's currently what I'm trying to accomplish....

```
Private Sub FrmSummary_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Me.MdiParent = MDIForm1

    InitializeComponent()

'Here I want to call a function to load the datagridView(with g_frmName)see below...
    call LoadDataGrid(frmName)
End Sub
```

Is something like that a smart idea? Or should I/Can I directly call the function from the previous form? 
Just trying to see if I'm on the right track, if not, how can i do it in a sound way?

Comment: What happens when the user does something so that 2 forms need to show the frmSummary?

Comment: well they are only able to access the frmSummary from 1 out of the 5 at forms (only once, until they close out of frmSumarry then they can access it from another form). Basically they might be on form1, then they click summary. FrmSummary will actually open within their form. I just want a sound way to pass a value to frmSummary so that I can display data directly related to it. They they will close frmSummary with CLOSE button, and if they are on form2 and click Summary, frmSummary will pop up and with the parameter display the data related to form2

Comment: Then [pass the key/tag/info in the constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19261166/1070452)  Though uf each instance has its own action code, there is no reason you cant allow multiple copies

Comment: Sounds like it should be a singleton

Comment: Don't call `InitializeComponent()` in the `Load` event. It is supposed to be called by the constructor only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one frmSummary, you could make it a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

In frmSummary, put the following code:

```
Private Shared _instance As frmSummary

Private Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
End Sub

Public Shared Function GetInstance() As frmSummary
    If _instance Is Nothing Then
        _instance = New frmSummary()
    End If
    Return _instance
End Function

Public Sub PutDataInGrid(data As Object)
    Me.DataGridView1.' put data in it
End Sub
```

And you would access it from other forms like this

```
Dim myFrmSummary = frmSummary.GetInstance()
myFrmSummary.PutDataInGrid(myData)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly....

You can just set the required parameters in the `New` declaration sub (Where `InitializeComponent()` is supposed to be). On your form, declare variables and set one to each of the parameter values, and set up your form this way..

An example might be;

```
Public Class frmSummary

Dim var1 as String = ""
Dim var2 as Boolean = True

Public Sub New(ByVal parameter1 as String, ByVal parameter2 As Boolean)

  var1 = parameter1
  var2 = parameter2

 InitializeComponent()


End Sub

Private Sub frmSummary_Load(sender as Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

  If var1 = "This String" Then
   If var2 = False Then
    sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable"
      ' Rest of your code to get the DGV data
     DataGridView1.DataSource = Dt
    Else
   End If
  End If

End Sub
```

Again, I may have misunderstood the question, so apologies if that is the case.

Comment: @david no you understood correctly. I'm doing the same thing in my application. I just wanted to make sure this is the right way to do it. Thank you!

Comment: @Verdolino Oops, my bad. I meant because the OP had it in the `Load` event, I didn't mean to miss it out

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. Never seen it called in Form_Load but it seems to work? Though visual studio gives a warning when it's in `Form_Load` *Private Sub New()' in designer-generated type 'WindowsApplication2.frmSummary' should call InitializeComponent method.*. No biggie

Comment: @Verdolino I think it would probably behave differently too, without actually trying it out. It would need to go at the top of the `Load` method, at the very least, so the compiler wasn't trying to fill a `DataGridView` before calling it, for example.

Comment: @David `InitializeComponent()` will need to be moved to the `New` method. It's the first thing the method should call then you would assign the passed parameters to `var1` and `var2`.

Comment: @Jinx88909 Oops, moved it to the wrong place initially. Either way, the order they go in doesn't matter, I put it after I've assigned the variables in personally.

Comment: @David :) Not sure if it does matter to be honest. I just follow the comment `' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.`.

Comment: @Jinx88909 I think that refers more the actual controls loading the form data than variable assigning