# How to write data in a Form when it has already been opened?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am carrying out a project for a restaurant, in which a Form is presented to me on a second monitor that lists the products that the client is invoicing, this sale opens when the application starts.

The problem is that at the time I am making the invoice, I need to send you the data to represent the product, `price`, `subtotal`, `vat` and `total` of the invoice.
My problem is that when the parameters are sent, they are not reflected on the screen only in the code, through a breakpoint.

On the Label where the zero value is reflected, `36` should appear, which is the number corresponding to the invoice.

I hope you can help, thank you.

```
enter code here
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your code is missing -- You should probably use data bindings, so when you change the data, all bound Controls will update automatically -- As a side note, you're designing at a high scale, you'll probably have some issue when deploying in a machine with a much lower scale.

Comment: Could you give me an example how I can do this task?

Comment: Maybe, when you show your code, so it will hopefully clear enough what objects you're working with and what kind of operations you want to perform. -- You skipped [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) when presented to you, so you didn't visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), so you probably didn't read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem at hand. This one, you need to read it.

Comment: Another important part you have not read in the Help Center is that posting code as images is not exactly what is expected: nobody can copy/paste your code for testing it. Hence, it's useless. -- Build some code that can reproduce the issue and paste it here. It's also much simpler than posting images of it.

Comment: Attach image with code sample, sorry if there is text in Spanish.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!
Please avoid screenshots. Post actual code that can be searched and read well.
Read [this guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) with markdown formatting tips.

Comment: I can't se any line of code that looks like it will pass data from one form to the other. Please point out which of your lines of code passes the data

Comment: Which screen the form is on doesn't matter when passing data to a form (or between forms). Search for "form communication".

Comment: Are you looking for : [Passing parameters between two forms in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531180/passing-parameters-between-two-forms-in-vb-net) ? please provide more related code instead of pictures here.