# Send Parameter via new() or pre-set properties before calling the new form?

Tags: vb.net, windows, winforms

I would really appreciate your advice on the following:
I'm working on Windows forms using VB.NET (even though the language is irrelevant to the question at hand).
I've got a main form and wish to call out another one, however depending on a given variable I need the text on some of the new form's elements to change as well as disable some of its controls.
There are two ways I see of doing it:

1. Send a parameter from the main form and have some logic on the second form to deal with everything on load.

Main Form:

```
dim newform as new frmcalculate(byval type as string)
```

New Form:

```
public sub getexplanation(byval type as string) 
 select type
   case "Sum"
      lblexplanation.text = "this is a sum"
   case "Subtraction"
      lblexplanation.text = "this is a subtraction"
End sub
```

2. Set exactly what I want on the main form before calling the new form.
   i.e:

   ```
   dim newform as new frmcalculate()
   newform.lblexplanation.text = "This is a sum"
   ```

I hope I've managed to explain it correctly.
I'm still new at this especially getting the formats right on Stackoverflow.

Comment: What is the question??!!

Comment: [Use copies of a Form](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19254028/1070452) would likely help.  Your first snippet doesnt create an instance (and isnt valid code): `Dim newform as New frmcalculate(strType)`  You could also add a property to the target form and set it

Comment: @h.fadlallah please read the title. There is the question.

Comment: @Plutonix Thank you for revising it. But the code I've just mocked up. It's not the real code as this isn't a code related question.
What I would like to find out is what is the best practice. To set the properties before or to have the form that gets called handle it on the load event.

Comment: The answer depends on how it is used.  If the target form requires the information to operate use the constructor.  If it can change, expose it as a property.  In other cases a method might be better for passing data that changes (like a charting form maybe)

Comment: @Plutonix it is just text or disabling a control which can easily be accessible from the form that calls the other one.

Comment: One form fiddling with the controls on another form is a bad idea.

Comment: @plutonix Awesome! Exactly what I wanted to know (if bad practice or not) How can I give you a thumbs up as in these little comments at the bottom I cant seem to have that option. Also is there anyway to PM or get like a mentor someone who I could normally go to ask for advice and stuff like this. Someone with more experience than me. As I aim to be constantly improving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first approach the code is best managed and organized for further editing. So each form has it own code.

It is not best practice to use second approach. (Editing a form designer from another one)